# efficiently removing entities with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using a one-to-many with a join table association in doctrine. An `Asset` has many `Attribute`s.

I'm trying to get doctrine to *not* issue individual attribute delete queries when removing an asset.

Here's my test

```
$asset = new Asset($assetId = AssetId::generate(), 'foobar');
$attribute = new Attribute((string)AssetId::generate(),  rand());
$asset->addAttribute($attribute);
$attribute = new Attribute((string)AssetId::generate(),  rand());
$asset->addAttribute($attribute);
$this->em->persist($asset);
$this->em->flush();

$asset = $this->em->getRepository(Asset::CLASS)->find((string)$assetId);
$this->em->remove($asset);
$this->em->flush();
```

And here are the queries doctrine issues

```
string(19) ""START TRANSACTION""
string(47) "INSERT INTO attributes (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)"
string(47) "INSERT INTO attributes (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)"
string(43) "INSERT INTO ASSETS (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)"
string(67) "INSERT INTO asset_attributes (asset_id, attribute_id) VALUES (?, ?)"
string(67) "INSERT INTO asset_attributes (asset_id, attribute_id) VALUES (?, ?)"
string(8) ""COMMIT""
string(19) ""START TRANSACTION""
string(31) "DELETE FROM ASSETS WHERE id = ?"
string(35) "DELETE FROM attributes WHERE id = ?"
string(35) "DELETE FROM attributes WHERE id = ?"
string(8) ""COMMIT""
```

I'm trying to get rid of the two delete queries against the `attributes` table and instead issue a single query like below

```
DELETE FROM attributes where asset_id = ?
```

I know doctrine is issuing the individual deletes because of the `cascade: ["all"]` configuration but if i just set it to `persist`, no delete queries will be run.

Is this possible?

Here's is my yml config

```
MyCompany\MyProject\Model\Entity\Asset:
    type: entity
    table: ASSETS
    id:
        id:
            type: string
            length: 36
            generator:
                strategy: none
    fields:
        name:
            type: string

    manyToMany:
        attributes:
            targetEntity: MyCompany\MyProject\Model\Entity\AssetAttribute\Attribute
            cascade: ["all"]
            fetch: LAZY
            orphanRemoval: true
            joinTable:
                name: asset_attributes
                joinColumns:
                    asset_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                        onDelete: CASCADE
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    attribute_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                        unique: true
```

Comment: Why do not performs a unique remove statement yourself instead let doctrine do it for you?

Comment: Yeah thats my backup plan. I feel like this would be something doctrine should be able to do though

Comment: Another nice option is create a foreign key in db table. So delete a record at parent table will trigger delete every children

Comment: @manix i'm using a join table so i can't really do that. Both the Assets and Attributes tables don't have columns referencing each other. However, the join table does have foreign keys, so the rows in the join table will be deleted if the asset is deleted but not the actual attribute row :/